# How can I get eclipse to pick up maven dependencies when running a unit test

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing

I have a unit test that runs fine via maven. If I run the test in eclipse by right-click the test and selecting Run As -> Junit Test the test fails. It fails because of a missing maven dependency.To get the test to pass in Eclipse I have to add the dependency manually by adding the jar to the class path in the Run Configuration. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does Eclipse recognize your project as a Maven project? What scope has that dependency?

Comment: Eclipse does recognise the project as a Maven project and the dependency is in test scope. I have fixed the problem. I found the answer here - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html. I had to add additionalClasspathElements to my pom file.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I had to add this to my pom file:

```
<additionalClasspathElements>
<additionalClasspathElement>${user.home}/.m2/repository/path/to/jar/file</additionalClasspathElement>
</additionalClasspathElements>
```

Comment: Since the local repository is not necessarily located in your `{user.home}` (depending on the settings.xml), it should be more reliable to use `${settings.localRepository}` instead of `${user.home}/.m2/repository`